# How to display an options menu like this when buttons are pressed?

Tags: java, android, menu

I'm stuck figuring how to do the following requirement.

I need to make a simple screen with two buttons, like this:
[image]

That part of the screen is already done.

The hardest thing for me is to make the behavior of the two buttons
when they are pressed. In that case, they must show an option menu
below like this:

Button 1 Pressed:
[image]

Button 2 Pressed:

[image]

I didn't start to program the menu yet,but in case it helps, this is 
the layout for the screen (without the buttons).

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/grayBackgound"
    tools:context=".MenuActivity" >

    <include android:layout_width="match_parent" layout="@layout/header" />
    <include android:layout_width="match_parent" layout="@layout/loggedin_subheader"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The layout for the header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >    

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/header"
        android:contentDescription="@string/header" 
     />


     <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/btnClose"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_close"
            android:contentDescription="@+string/salir"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="260dp"
      />


</FrameLayout>
```

The layout for the sub-header is almost the same.

I just need help to make the options menu for every button.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The menu that you want to implement is what is commonly called a `QuickAction Dialog`. There are several tutorials available for that.

To get you started, here is a few links:

1. http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/
2. https://github.com/ruqqq/WorldHeritageSite (This is not a tutorial per se, but has the complete implementation for the `QuickAction Dialog`)
3. https://code.google.com/p/simple-quickactions/ (You will need to make a few modifications in this)

The first link is the most promising in your case. If you scroll down that page to the **Gallery3D-like QuickActions** section, you will see it kind of resembles what you want the end result in your app to be. Naturally, goes without saying, you will still need to make modifications to the source available on the site.

Hope this helps. ;-)

Comment: thanks Siddharth! I'll try to adapt the example to my use case!

Comment: @Lucas: Glad to have been of help. Good luck. :-)